# Script to write endless letters combinations (Regex / ASCII)

Tags: php, python, regex, bash, perl

I'm trying to create a .txt file of all possible combinations of all ASCII letters (at least the latin ones) by the following requirements:

A.  1-5 letters
B.  a-z (and all possible cases of those letters)
C.  Spaces between 1st and 2nd, 2nd and 3rd, 3rd and 4th & 4th and 5th, for all possible combinations.

For exmaple:

```
a,
b,
c,
aa,
bb,
cc,
a bc,
aa b,
aaa cz,
ga l qa,
p j asd,
n ljas,
asdl q,
a q j o z;

etc. etc.
-----
```

I tried some things with PHP & Regex but its out of my league as I cannot miss a single match while writing this script.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: That's going to be *thousands* of GB.  If you're trying to construct a dictionary attack, just generate the perms on the fly.

Comment: That's not just about coding. You first have to plan what steps will your algorithm follow and then just type it. First: only one letter, then two, till all, and then, start space in first position, then 2nd, then 3rd, then combining... etc. Mind if I ask what is this for?

Comment: I think there are a bit over 6 billion combinations: `sum(52**n * 2**(n-1) for n in range(1,6))`

Comment: Its for keywords match for advertising, not attacking anything but the server that will run this long algorithm process to write it down to a text file.
Conditions are as following:
1. All matches from a-zzzzz (22^5 + 22^4 + 22^3 + 22^2 + 22^1)
2. All possible spaces between letters for 1's output. (+ Its' output)

Comment: Re "all ASCII letters (at least the latin ones)", ASCII only contains latin letters (unaccented a-z and A-Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general implementation that can be easily modified to handle different sets of characters `letters` and maximums lengths `n`.

Note that I commented out the original values for `maxLength` and `letters` and chose `maxLength = 3` and `letters = "ABC"` for testing purposes. Actually, I don't think that computing all required combinations is tractable. I didn't try it.

```py
import itertools

# maxLength = 5
# letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
maxLength = 3
letters = "ABC"

for length in range(1, maxLength + 1):
    string = [""] * (2 * length - 1)
    for combination in itertools.product(letters, repeat=length):
        string[::2] = combination
        for blanks in itertools.product(["", " "], repeat=length-1):
            string[1::2] = blanks
            print "".join(string)
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
AA
A A
AB
A B
.
.
.
CCB
CC B
C CB
C C B
CCC
CC C
C CC
C C C
```

Comment: Thanks, 2 issues with this script:
1. It stops at C C C
2. It misses the match of A BB for example (or A CC, C CC etc.)

Comment: I updated the script (fixed a bug and simplified another part). Issue 1: As mentioned above, I restrict the combinations to the tiny subset ```A``` to ```C C C```, since a complete run would take forever. Issue 2: This was a bug, but should work now.

Comment: Thanks, its nearly everything, just missing the matches of all letters coming before the letter before the current one (eg. A b a, a ba - won't be present at this script ATM)

Comment: Sorry its all there, just the linux shell can't handle it anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this using [`Algorithm::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Combinatorics).

One trick that makes the problem somewhat simpler is recognizing that `"a"` and `" a"` can just be treated as two different letters, so we're actually just dealing with one group of 52 possible letters (upper and lower) followed by groups of 104 possible letters (upper and lower, and prefix with a space or not).

The following script demonstrates for a much smaller sublet of permutations:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(variations_with_repetition);

#my $maxlength = 5;
#my @letters   = ( 'a' .. 'z', 'A' .. 'Z' );
my $maxlength = 3;
my @letters   = ( 'a' .. 'c' );

for my $prefix (@letters) {
    print "$prefix\n";
    for my $length ( 1 .. $maxlength - 1 ) {
        my $iter = variations_with_repetition( [ map { ( $_, " $_" ) } @letters ], $length );
        while ( my $p = $iter->next ) {
            print $prefix, @$p, "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
a
aa
a a
ab
a b
ac
a c
aaa
aa a
aab
aa b
aac
aa c
a aa
a a a
a ab
a a b
a ac
a a c
aba
ab a
abb
ab b
abc
ab c
a ba
a b a
a bb
a b b
a bc
a b c
aca
ac a
acb
ac b
acc
ac c
a ca
a c a
a cb
a c b
a cc
a c c
b
ba
b a
bb
b b
bc
b c
baa
ba a
bab
ba b
bac
ba c
b aa
b a a
b ab
b a b
b ac
b a c
bba
bb a
bbb
bb b
bbc
bb c
b ba
b b a
b bb
b b b
b bc
b b c
bca
bc a
bcb
bc b
bcc
bc c
b ca
b c a
b cb
b c b
b cc
b c c
c
ca
c a
cb
c b
cc
c c
caa
ca a
cab
ca b
cac
ca c
c aa
c a a
c ab
c a b
c ac
c a c
cba
cb a
cbb
cb b
cbc
cb c
c ba
c b a
c bb
c b b
c bc
c b c
cca
cc a
ccb
cc b
ccc
cc c
c ca
c c a
c cb
c c b
c cc
c c c
```

#### Addendum

For fun I created a script that works through the permutations and adds the spaces in afterwords:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(variations_with_repetition);
use List::MoreUtils qw(mesh);

#my $maxlength = 5;
#my @letters   = ( 'a' .. 'z', 'A' .. 'Z' );
my $maxlength = 3;
my @letters   = ( 'a' .. 'c' );

for my $length ( 1 .. $maxlength ) {
    my $iter = variations_with_repetition( \@letters, $length );
    while ( my $p = $iter->next ) {
        print @$p, "\n";
        for my $spaces ( 1 .. 2**( $length - 1 ) - 1 ) {
            my @spaces = (map({$_ ? ' ' : ''} split //, sprintf "%0*b", $length - 1, $spaces), '');
            print mesh(@$p, @spaces), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Falko's Python script covers all options ++, But I see you are all enjoying yourselves so I'll have more soon :)